# Strange recursive folder created on npm installation

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, nodejs, npm

something very strange is happening to my system. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I use it for node.js deveopment. Every time I perform an installation either (`sudo npm install -g myPackage`) a srtange folder is created: `[sudo] password for emanuele:` cointaining a recursive infinite structure:

```
[sudo] password for emanuele: /home/emanuele/[sudo] password for emanuele: /home/emanuele/[sudo] password for emanuele: /home/emanuele/[sudo] password for emanuele: /home/emanuele/[sudo] password for emanuele: /home/emanuele/[sudo] password for emanuele: /home/emanuele/[sudo] password for emanuele:
```

and so on (emanuele is my username, off course).

I didn't know what caused this. I haven't seen anything like that!

Answer (score 2):

Set the prefix to `/usr/local` using this:

```
npm set prefix /usr/local  
npm install -g phon
```

Source:

[Installing Phonegap with NPM 1 3 11 creates a password directory path on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092293/installing-phonegap-with-npm-1-3-11-creates-a-password-directory-path-on-mac-os)

It worked for me